# Redis pubsub cause Too Many Files Open Error

Tags: python, redis, publish-subscribe

I have a server used Redis and Socket.IO. If a user connect to the socket.IO, server will run a greenlet and subscribe to redis channel. If the user disconnect, the greenlet will unsubscribe the channel.

After a lot of connection and disconnection, I use 'client list' command in redis-cli, I found that the number of unsubscribe is additive and it will never closed like other command. And it will finally cause 'Too Many Files Open Error'  [image]

My Code is

```
class ListenMsgThreading(Greenlet):
    def __init__(self, app_eui, request_sid):
        Greenlet.__init__(self)
        self.ps = redis_db.pubsub()
        self.ps.subscribe('channel')

    def stop(self):
        self.ps.unsubscribe('channel')

    def run(self):
        for item in self.ps.listen():
            if item is not None:
                print(item)
```

I notice that the reason may be

> timeout only applies to number clients and it does not apply to Pub/Sub clients, since a Pub/Sub connection is a push style connection so a client that is idle is the norm.

Should I implement the timeout for unsubscribe command? Or use other method to stop subscribe?

Comment: is `redis_db` an actual StrictRedis() object?

Comment: Yes. The redis_db is a StrictRedis() object.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code

https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/redis/client.py#L2281

I can guess at the issue.  It looks like the PubSub object checks a connection out of the connection pool on the `subscribe` command, but doesn't release it on `unsubscribe`.  It SHOULD release it when your greenlet goes out of scope (the `del` method)- are you holding them in scope for some reason so that they don't get freed?  This will lead to memory issues either way...

however, you could try using the `reset` method to force release that connection without messing with scope issues.

```
self.ps.unsubscribe()
self.ps.reset()
```

Comment: self.ps.reset() will close all the current alive connection and raise an other error as: redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error while reading from socket: (9, 'File descriptor was closed in another greenlet')